# Single Rails codebase, two servers, two routing scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In a rails application with namespaced /admin functionality, consider the following routes:

```
 namespace :admin do
   root :to => 'home#index'
   [.. resources cut here..]
 end

 get 'etc/:etc' => 'etc#etc'
 [.. other top level routes cut..]
```

If I wanted to deploy the same Rails codebase to 2 separate servers, frontend.com would still see the top level routes 'etc/:etc'.

But what if I wanted to deploy the same codebase to an admin-only server, such that the request would simply be http://backend.com and have namespace :admin take over as the top level without having to type or use http://backend.com/admin.

Upon trying with .htaccess rewrite, I have run into URL generation issues within the admin namespace code, as well as assets no longer being loaded properly.

Is this just something that's not worth pursuing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, of course, have a conditional around a root statement.

```
namespace :admin do
  root :to => 'admin#index'
  ...
end
if SOMETHING
  root :to => "admin#index"
end
```

(I used an AdminController instead of HomeController in this example.)

The user can type http://backend.com/, but at some point the /admin may appear on the browser's URL bar.

The SOMETHING could be a test for the hostname, or an ENV.  You could set the ENV in the vhost configuration.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to forward to the admin namespace from top level?  if SOMETHING; root :to => 'admin::admin#index' or something similar?

Comment: My guess would be "admin/admin#index".

Comment: Actually, it appears root :to => 'admin::Home#index' (for admin namespace, home controller) works!  Thanks for your help.  I believe this is a solved problem now.